# How to get paperwork for horses?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

When I steal a horse, or catch one in the wild and bring it back to a stable, the stable owner mumbles something like:

> "I can't give you that much for this horse without the right
>   paperwork"

Is it possible to acquire paperwork for horses that you steal, or catch in the wild to sell for more money at stables? If so, how?

Comment: I interpreted it more as an explanation for the disparity in price between selling and buying, and a historical accuracy nod.  I haven't seen any mention of it past the first dialogue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot acquire paperwork for horses. You can, however, find merchants willing to buy a horse with no papers (at a less reduced price).

During chapter 3, you will be introduced to a horse fence. This is similar to the fence you unlock during chapter 2, except that these guys (only) buy horses.

For horses with papers, stables will buy them for more than a horse fence will.
For horses without papers, horse fences will buy them for more than a stable will.